# Storing geo data

Tags: sql-server-2005, geolocation, geotagging

Hi I'm using ms sql 2005 to store some latlng data.
It is currently being stored in a nvarchar column in the following form - "35.6949965,139.7555035"
My questions are.
Is this the best way to store this kind of data?
If I do store the latlng in this way is it going to come and bite me later, or will it mean just that I will have to do any processing outside of the database?

Any pointers appreciated,

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but are you sure this will store a unique location? As far as I know you will have to store N/S and E/W along with latitude and longitude.

Comment: @Rekreativc: that can be done by using the sign (negative values are usually S/W).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly not the best way to store it.  If you use a pair of floating-point columns - latitude and longitude - then you can perform some functions within the database itself.  As an example, here's how to calculate the distance between two points:

http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.mssql.html

Or, as a trivial example,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE latitide<40;
```

would find everywhere north of New York.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you'd update to MSSQL 2008 and use the new [GEOGRAPHY data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx). This would allow you to use all kinds of nifty features, like spatial indexes that efficiently do queries like "give me all points within a 100 mile radius of 35.6949965,139.7555035".

Comment: Thanks. If I store as numeric values for now - would I be able to convert to the Geo Type easily later?

Comment: @Chin: migrating the database should not be a big issue, but migrating the code that uses it (and implements all the geodata functionality that the geography type gives you) probably will.